# How to make outline shader with Unity shader graph

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to make an Outline shader, but only achieved the following. Works perfectly exclusively on the sphere. And in Cuba, it hardly works at all. Who have to use the Shader Graph, please help! [image: my outline tests]

Comment: Feel free to try [this solution](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1065843/view.html).

Comment: This is just an attempt to recreate the Outline Shader. And I wanted to know, here, how all such to make this Shader!

Comment: @Draco18s I need for Shader Graph

Comment: I have no idea then. Because in order to get an even thickness around models, you need to have a `geom` method that creates new geometry as well as two render passes with a stencil mask. And I don't know if Shader Graph even *supports* either of those.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recreate your shader, do you have the correct shader type?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: but this is not the correct way to do this. the outline will not have the same thickness over the whole thing and the lines will be at places were it does not count as "outline"

Comment: That's the problem I meant, did you read the headline? This is just an attempt to recreate the Outline Shader. And I wanted to know, here, how all such to make this Shader!

Answer (score 1):

the effect that you're creating there is going to put an emission on faces that are a certain angle. it does not work to create an outline shader in the shader editor. here is a youtube tutorial to create the type of effect that you're trying to achieve https://youtu.be/SMLbbi8oaO8
[image]

Comment: Well, can you make the outline lay down on the object when hidden behind some object, and not on the object behind which is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I have found a very easy way to do a simple outline shader. This is in the newest version of Unity (Unity 2022.1.0b14.2951).

Here's the graph:
[image: Shader Graph]

Here are the settings:

[image: Shader Settings]

And here are the results:

[image]

It starts to show its negative qualities when two outlined objects intersect, however.